# SQL "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'."

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm new to SQL and visual studio etc. but I've changed something that isn't allowing me to login to my application. Whenever I press the login button I get this error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'

Here is where the source may be;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace RockPaperApp
{
  public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
  {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["New"] != null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("/Game.aspx");
        }
    }

    protected void RegButton_Press(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("/Register.aspx");
    }

    protected void LogButton_Press(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string username = UsernameLogTxt.Text;

        try
        {
            string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["UserConS"].ToString();
            string CommandText = "pword from data Username=@username";

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conn.ToString()))
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(CommandText, connection))
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
                connection.Open();

                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        string realpass = reader[0].ToString();

                        if (realpass != PasswordLogTxt.Text)
                        {
                            Response.Write("<span style='color:red'>A Wrong Username of Password has been entered.</span>");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Session["New"] = UsernameLogTxt.Text;
                            Response.Redirect("/Game.aspx");
                        }
                    }

                    if (!reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        Response.Write("No such username exists.");
                    }
                }
                connection.Close();
            }

        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            Response.Write( ex.Message);
        }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Register.aspx");
    }
  }      
}
```

Comment: Although probably not important for this question: when asking SQL questions **always** add  the tag corresponding to your DBMS (`postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, ...). **SQL** is a query language, not a DBMS product.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a valid SQL query:

```
"pword from data Username=@username"
```

Maybe you copied/pasted *part* of a query when you meant to copy/paste the whole thing?  It doesn't even look like a valid *part* of a query, though.

The error is telling you that the problem is at keyword `from` because that's the first thing it encounters after the error.  For SQL errors, always look at the very last thing that was parsed before the location of the error, that last thing is what caused it.  In this case the keyword `pword` caused it, since that's not a valid keyword or identifier in SQL and the query parser couldn't make sense of it.

**Side note:** All too often on Stack Overflow we have to lecture developers, new and experienced alike, for SQL injection vulnerabilities.  This is a rare chance where I get to personally *commend* you for taking the initiative to use parameterized queries despite your relatively new experience level.  I'm genuinely impressed, please keep up the good work!

**Another side note:** Though, you *are* also storing passwords in plain text, which is a *very very bad* thing.  It's better to hash the password and store the hash.  Then when a user enters a password, hash what they enter and compare it against the stored hash.  Once you get this working, I hope you address that as well :)

Comment: Yeah pretty much this - pasting sort of notes, rather than full syntax. Thank you!

Comment: @user2974706: Please see my update as well.  While your code has a mistake, it also has a *very good thing* that I hope you continue to use :)

Comment: our lecturer really drilled it into us . The importance has stuck :) thank you!

Comment: @user2974706: I just made another update, and one you can bring back to your lecturer to drill into him, because he needs to remember it :)

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL needs to be: `SELECT pword FROM data WHERE Username=@username`.

The capitalization of the keywords (`SELECT`, `FROM`, `WHERE`) doesn't matter.